# Raster to Polygon - trained raster classes from SVM into organized polygons

Tags: raster, polygon, arcgis-pro

A little hard for me to explain so here are a few images. I am trying to create nice polygons of the classes. As you can see there are other classes mixed in but you can tell what the dominant class is:

[image]

[image]

Comment: So what have you tried? Majority filter?

Comment: I have tried majority filter, boundary clean, raster to polygon. All with okay results. The latest process is raster to point then a DBSCAN which actually created pretty nice clusters, but take VERY long to process.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the a [combination](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.9/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/smoothing-zone-edges-with-boundary-clean-and-majority-filter.htm) of the [Majority Filter](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.9/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/majority-filter.htm) and [Boundary Clean](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.9/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/boundary-clean.htm) tools in the [Generalization toolset](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.9/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/an-overview-of-the-generalization-tools.htm).

From the doc:

> The generalization analysis tools are used to either clean up small
> erroneous data in the raster or generalize the data to get rid of
> unnecessary detail for a more general analysis.
>
> There are several common sources for the erroneous data, such as the
> following:
>
> - Classified satellite imagery may contain many small areas of
>   misclassified cells.
> - etc...
>
> The generalization tools are divided into several general categories:
>
> - etc...
> - Those that [smooth zone edges](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.9/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/smoothing-zone-edges-with-boundary-clean-and-majority-filter.htm). (Boundary Clean and Majority Filter)

[image]

[image]